# aiogram-3.x anti-flood middleware

Tags: python, spam-prevention, aiogram

Is there some ways to do an Anti-Flood middleware in aiogram-3.x (beta), like in aiogram-2 [[example]](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/middleware_and_antiflood.html)

I tried search some examples about it across the aiogram-3 documentation, but there is no solutions for my problem
[documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Antiflood middleware for aiogram 3.2.0 using redis as storage:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import *
from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message
import redis.asyncio.client 
import time

class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, redis: redis.asyncio.client.Redis, limit = .5, key_prefix = 'antiflood_'):
        self.rate_limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        self.throttle_manager = ThrottleManager(redis = redis)

        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def __call__(
        self,
        handler: Callable[[Message, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
        event: Message,
        data: Dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Any:

        try:
            await self.on_process_event(event)
        except CancelHandler:
            # Cancel current handler
            return

        try:
            result = await handler(event, data)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)

        return result

    async def on_process_event(
        self, 
        event: Message,
    ) -> Any:

        limit = self.rate_limit
        key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        # Use ThrottleManager.throttle method.
        try:
            await self.throttle_manager.throttle(key, rate = limit, user_id = event.from_user.id, chat_id = event.chat.id)
        except Throttled as t:
            # Execute action
            await self.event_throttled(event, t)

            # Cancel current handler
            raise CancelHandler()

    async def event_throttled(self, event: Message, throttled: Throttled):
        # Calculate how many time is left till the block ends
        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta

        # Prevent flooding
        if throttled.exceeded_count <= 2:
            await event.answer(f'Too many events.\nTry again in {delta:.2f} seconds.')


class ThrottleManager:
    bucket_keys = [
        "RATE_LIMIT", "DELTA",
        "LAST_CALL", "EXCEEDED_COUNT"
    ]
    def __init__(self, redis: redis.asyncio.client.Redis):
        self.redis = redis

    async def throttle(self, key: str, rate: float, user_id: int, chat_id: int):
        now = time.time()
        bucket_name = f'throttle_{key}_{user_id}_{chat_id}'

        data = await self.redis.hmget(bucket_name, self.bucket_keys)
        data = {
            k: float(v.decode()) 
               if isinstance(v, bytes) 
               else v 
            for k, v in zip(self.bucket_keys, data) 
            if v is not None
        }

        # Calculate
        called = data.get("LAST_CALL", now)
        delta = now - called
        result = delta >= rate or delta <= 0

        # Save result
        data["RATE_LIMIT"] = rate
        data["LAST_CALL"] = now
        data["DELTA"] = delta
        if not result:
            data["EXCEEDED_COUNT"] += 1
        else:
            data["EXCEEDED_COUNT"] = 1

        await self.redis.hmset(bucket_name, data)

        if not result:
            raise Throttled(key=key, chat=chat_id, user=user_id, **data)
        
        return result

class Throttled(Exception):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.key = kwargs.pop("key", '<None>')
        self.called_at = kwargs.pop("LAST_CALL", time.time())
        self.rate = kwargs.pop("RATE_LIMIT", None)
        self.exceeded_count = kwargs.pop("EXCEEDED_COUNT", 0)
        self.delta = kwargs.pop("DELTA", 0)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.chat = kwargs.pop('chat', None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Rate limit exceeded! (Limit: {self.rate} s, " \
               f"exceeded: {self.exceeded_count}, " \
               f"time delta: {round(self.delta, 3)} s)"

class CancelHandler(Exception):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler, current_handler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled
import asyncio
from aiogram import types
from loader import *


def rate_limit(limit: float, key=None):
    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, 'throttling_rate_limit', limit)
        if key:
            setattr(func, 'throttling_key', key)
        return func

    return decorator


class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, limit=DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT, key_prefix='antiflood_'):
        self.rate_limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()

        if handler:
            limit = getattr(handler, 'throttling_rate_limit', self.rate_limit)
            key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            limit = self.rate_limit
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        try:
            await dispatcher.throttle(key, rate=limit)
        except Throttled as t:
            await self.message_throttled(message, t)
            raise CancelHandler()

    async def message_throttled(self, message: types.Message, throttled: Throttled):

        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        if handler:
            key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta

        await asyncio.sleep(delta)

        thr = await dispatcher.check_key(key)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).